# What protocol does Octopus deploy use for publishing content to Azure Web Apps?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, octopus-deploy

Does Octopus deploy use MSDeploy or something else to publish the content to web app? I read their article and couldn't find anything substantial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it uses MSDeploy.

You can see some evidence in the [Calamari repository](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Calamari/blob/94e883c84e8605a7b032492e23e813e369811733/source/Calamari.Azure/Deployment/Conventions/AzureWebAppConvention.cs#L46) (which is open source).